# Does submitting in PhilArchive affect submission in journals?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, preprint, philosophy

I wanted to submit a paper to PhilArchive (an open-access e-print archive in philosophy). If I want to submit this paper to a journal afterwards, does this prior submission to PhilArchive affect the journal's decision?

Comment: That is up to the journal to decide. Some won't touch it, but this is also field dependent to some extent. I'd guess that Open Access is a particular problem, though. What incentive does the journal have?

Comment: @Buffy, Thanks for your answer. I know it is field-dependent, so I asked this question in philosophy stackchange, but they advised me to ask it here. I did not decide which journal fits best, but I think it is better to check the possible candidates.

Comment: @TheDoctor, Thank you. No, it does not answer my question because the situation differs by different fields of study. In mathematics and computer science, publishing its preprints on ArXiv is mostly okay. However, the case can be different in other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the guidelines of the journals you are interested to publish in. As you say, it differs between different fields, but also between different journals within fields. Some journals explicitly say that they will not approve anything that has been previously published anywhere, including places such as PhilArchive.

In my experience, philosophy journals are less likely to have such policies, and I know many philosophy professors who publish their papers there and on other similar places, without publishing them elsewhere first, or elsewhere at all.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I will do as you've suggested.